# Fatal error: Call to undefined function gdlr_print_header_social()

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

when i open my site i get blank page after enable the display error then i get in my wordpress site this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function gdlr_print_header_social() in
>   /home2/u9447441/public_html/wp-content/themes/clevercourse-v1-27/header.php
>   on line 60

and my header.php page code is 
 on line 60 i found this line

```
            <div class="top-social-wrapper">
            <?php gdlr_print_header_social(); ?>
            </div>
```

how i reslove please help

Answer (score 0):

Call to undefined function error shows that it's not getting your function where you have defined. Please check your functions file. Maybe there is a spelling mistake.